# Can't open cgcookie flex rig

Tags: blend-files

I downloaded the "cgcookie flex rig" zipfile but when I try to open it in blender, the whole blender app disappears on my screen. Does anyone know how I can fix this.

I have a windows 10 (32 bit) if that helps.

Comment: Windows 10 32bit? What sort of graphics card on board? What about other blend files do you have issue with them as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image]

source : http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/61707

I added the license and packed the textures into the file. I'm still on windows 8 but I can confirm it opens in 2.78a.